# Get Current Financial Year In Acumatica Generic Inquiry

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way to retrieve the current financial year in Acumatica when building a GI? I have already built a generic inquiry and wanted to limit it to display only the current financial year transactions. I have already joined the Financial Periods table but cannot make this work unless I hardcode the financial year in the parameters

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 2):

There is no notion of "current" financial year - you can have multiple financial years open at once. What you could do is retrieve the earliest one open through the `FinPeriod` table.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do something useful with the Month(Today()) and Year(Today()) feature when writing a formula, I am not sure this was available months ago :) I can now compare the financial year based on the current month and current year (when month > 7, jump to the next year, otherwise the current year). This way, I can pick the FinPeriodID I was after.